# $f\left ( x \right )=\frac{logx}{x}$ What is the sign of $f'\left ( x \right )$? $0<x<1$

Tags: derivatives, logarithms

$$f'\left ( x \right )=\frac{1-logx}{x^{2}}$$

How can we say that $f'$ is positive? How can we be sure about the value of $log x$?

Comment: $\log x<0$ if $0<x<1$.

Comment: I didn't know derivatives could sigh ;o)

Comment: The sign of logarithm ($\ln$) changes in $x=1$. For $0<x<1$ it's negative and for $x>1$ it's positive.

Comment: @Bernard, sigh should occur for spleen functions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that for positive $x$
$$
(\ln x)'=\frac{1}{x}>0.
$$
It means that $f(x)=\ln x$ is a strictly increasing function. Furthermore, we know that $\ln 1=0$, hence, the strict monotonicity of $\ln$ ensures that for $0<x<1$
$$
\ln x<\ln 1=0
$$
and, thus,
$$
\frac{1-\ln x}{x^2}>\frac{1}{x^2}>0.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Look here for $0<x<1$, $log(x)<0$ which implies that $1-log(x)$ is positive in $0<x<1$.

So, $f'(x)=\frac{1-log(x)}{x^2}$ is positive there.